# How are these overloading methods different from each other?

Tags: c++, oop

So this method lies in **Vector3D** class. Could somebody please tell me how would I use it?

```
    Vector3D &operator*=(const double factor){
        x *= factor;
        y *= factor;
        z *= factor;
        return *this;
    }
```

And how is it different from this method?

```
inline Vector3D operator*(double s, const Vector3D &v) {
    return Vector3D(s * v.getX(), s * v.getY(), s * v.getZ());
}
```

Comment: It depends on the rest of implementation of `Vector3D`.

Comment: The difference is that one is `operator *=` and the other is `operator *`.

Comment: They have different return types, different names, different arguments, different code in them, and one's a member function and one isn't. How are these functions *not* different?

Comment: They're not even overloads of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator *=` appears to modify an existing `Vector3D` object. Its value is changed by the operator.

`operator *` does not modify an existing `Vector3D` object, it creates a new instance of this class, apparently to represent the value of the multiplication operator, and returns the new object. The existing objects remain unchanged.

It's the same as the difference between

```
 int a;

 int b;


 // ...

 a *= b;
```

The value of 'a' is multiplied by 'b', with 'a' now containing the multiplied result, and:

```
 c = a * b;
```

You multiply `a` with `b`, with the result of the multiplication going somewhere else. The original values of `a` and `b` are unchanged.

Comment: An example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @sashankAryal Doesn't the answer give examples?  With `operator *=`, the existing object is modified.  With `operator *` a brand new object is created and returned (the existing object is not modified).